# What is the best way to display a text that keeps updating

Tags: android, textview

I want to display some text that indicates the progress of my application. The text keeps updating which means that I will continue to append to it. I have used textView but when the text goes beyond it's size the application crashes. So what is the best way to display such text?

Note: In the activity that contains the text I don't have any other items beside the text view and a button.

here is the xml file of the activity the button is not created yet

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Locate" >

  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/scrollBody"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/log"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
      </LinearLayout>
```

here is my code

```
public class Locate extends Activity {

    List<ScanResult> wifiList;
    Timer timer ;
    public static int counter;
    int interval;
    int scansPerLoc;
    StringBuilder Res;
    boolean scanning;
    int port;
    String IP;
    private Socket client;

    private WifiManager Wifi;
    private WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
    private IntentFilter filter;
    private Toast toast;
    private Context context;
    private TextView log;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_locate);

        counter=0;
        // setting the android environment 
        context=this;
        Wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        filter= new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        timer = new Timer();
        Res = new StringBuilder();
        scanning=false;
        receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, filter);

        log=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.log);
        log.append("Locator:\n");
        toast=Toast.makeText(context, "Locating", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        //setting pars
    if(Settings.setting==true)
    {
          interval=Settings.interval;
        scansPerLoc=Settings.scansPerLoc;

    }
    else
    {
         interval=200;
         scansPerLoc=5;
    }


    receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
    registerReceiver(receiverWifi, filter);
    Wifi.startScan();


    toast=Toast.makeText(context, interval +"  "+scansPerLoc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();


    if(scanning)
    {
           timer.cancel();
    }
    else 
    {

        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(counter==scansPerLoc)
                {
                    scanning=false;
                    timer.cancel();
                    log.append("Finished Collecting RSSIs.");
                }
                else
                {

                    scanning=true;
                    if(wifiList!=null)
                    {
                        if(wifiList.size()!=0)
                        for(int i=0;i< wifiList.size();i++)
                        {
                            log.append((i+1)+" "+wifiList.get(i).BSSID+" "+wifiList.get(i).level+" ");
                            Res.append((i+1)+" "+wifiList.get(i).BSSID+" "+wifiList.get(i).level+" ");
                        //  format i : BSSID : RSSI : i :BSSID : RSSI
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Res.append("Empty");
                        log.append("No results");
                    }


                }
            }
        },0,interval);
    }

    if(counter==scansPerLoc)
    {
        if(!Settings.setting)
        {
            //show and ask for the settings
            toast=Toast.makeText(context, "The server parameters are not set yet, please set them", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }


    }// end of on create

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.locate, menu);
        return true;
    }


    class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

          wifiList=Wifi.getScanResults();



        }//end of on receive

  }// end of class


      protected void onPause() {
            unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);

            super.onPause();
        }

        protected void onResume()
        {
            registerReceiver(receiverWifi,filter);
            super.onResume();
        }
}
```

Comment: Would you illustrate your problem with the code you already have?

Comment: You can use [EditText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html), it supports multi-line text

Comment: Is it critical to have all previous update messages? If you just needed the last one, or even the last 10, 20, or 50, you could then avoid the memory issue. Other options could be to archive old messages to a file, and then recover them as your scroll back up. Just a few alternative options, if you can't find the answer you're looking for.

Comment: @PulkitSethi I think I will write the updates to a file